# Как правильно подключить jar библиотеку?

Tags: java, исключения, jdbc

Имеется программа, которая работает с БД используя JDBC. 
В intellij Idea программа прекрасно работает, но как только компилирую вручную и пытаюсь запустить из командной строки я получаю эксепшн.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/blabla
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Запуск произвожу с помощью такой команды:

```
java -cp .;"D:\libs\poi-3.14-20160307.jar" Main
```

Вроде и путь до библиотеки указал.

Если нужен исходный код - дополню вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAR jdbc-драйвера тоже стоит добавить в classpath:
java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar;"D:\libs\poi-3.14-20160307.jar" Main